# Remembering a file in case form fails

Tags: php

I have a form, all my fields have a script that allows to remember the datas that have been entered in case the forms fail to be submitted.

example

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])){echo $_POST["title"];}?>">
```

I have a input type="file" in my form as well ... is there any way to do the same to the selected file in case the form fails? having a way to remember the selected file...?

Comment: No, since that would be a security issue and can't remember the image that was chosen in the person's computer/folder. At best, use a ternary operator with a default value.

Comment: all of the duplicates this was closed with, basically explains what I said in comments. My answer was just much shorter.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah your 100% right.. I added a Django one to also point out the issue is language agnostic.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Right on ;-)

Comment: TBH I couldnt find anymore on google ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I think you've done enough *lol!* - Ok, I'm outta this one.